# REGEX With bind variable inside flow screen not working

Tags: visual-workflow, regular-expressions, bind-variable

i'm doing a field validation inside a flow screen with the regex formula field:

```
!REGEX({!CustomerNumberList}, **{!Account_Customer_Number}**)
```

And it seems the second argument is not being binded by formula.

My question is, salesforce has this limitation or it's just a bug?